# Python: How to cut a string up and use parts of it and discard others

Tags: python, string

in Python3, I want to convert the following string:

`bpy.types.object.location.* std:label -1 editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html#bpy-types-object-location Transform Properties`

To this following string:

`("bpy.types.Object.location.*", "editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html"),`

Currently, I only have:

```
with open("objects.tmp") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "bpy.types." in line:
            fw ('    ("' + line.rstrip() +'")\n')
```

How can a cut the string at a specific point e.g. `*` or/and after X number of spaces?

Comment: By doing a tutorial and reading the documentation, then attempting it yourself... Also, the desired output you are showing is not a string.

Comment: Assuming all of your strings follow a similar pattern, you could try: `tuple(string.split()[0], string.split()[3])`... But that really is error-prone. What code do you have thus far?

Comment: You'll need to parse it. What decides what is kept? What have you tried?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to provide code for a coder in distress, you need to show that you have made a reasonable attempt at solving your problem _first_. A good way to demonstrate your efforts is to include the code you've written so far, and describe what is not working. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Thanks guys for the feed back, I edited the question to make it more specific and post what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
originalString = 'bpy.types.object.location.* std:label -1 editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html#bpy-types-object-location Transform Properties'

# this separates your string by spaces
split = originalString.split(' ') 

# first element is ready to go!
first_element = split[0] # 'bpy.types.object.location.*'

# second element needs to be cut at "#"
second_element = split[3] 
second_element = second_element[:second_element.find('#')] # editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html

# now you have your desired output
output = tuple(first_element, second_element)
```